# Get Custom label of people participating with my page through messenger

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I  am building a dashboard so I can easily view how many people currently have a specific label in my facebook messenger. I'm just developing this for my page that I'm admin at, so it's only for this one page.

The final result is this:

```
Label 1  - 38 People
Label 2 - 82 People
Label 3 - 47 People
```

First I get the participants using this endpoints: {page-id}/conversations?fields=participants
I get this sample:

```json
{
"data": [
{
"participants": {
"data": [
{
"name": "Particiapnt's name",
"id": "<psid>"
},
{
"name": "My Page Name",
"id": "<my-pageid>"
}
]
},
"id": "<thread-id>"
}
]
}
```

Now when I use participants id (psid) to get custom labels using this endpint: /custom_labels
I get this error:

```json
{
"error": {
"message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'xxxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100,
"error_subcode": 33,
"fbtrace_id": "A5kFh5U-xSMB83ZnQrbzEfy"
}
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What type of access token did you use, and what permissions have been granted?

Comment: Thanks  @CBroe for the replying.
 I use page access token in the graph explorer.
These are the permissions granted: 

`user_messenger_contact
pages_show_list
pages_messaging
pages_messaging_phone_number
pages_messaging_subscriptions
leads_retrieval
page_events
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_engagement`

Comment: Can you check that the `xxxxx` part here `Object with ID 'xxxxx' does not exist` shows the exact same ID, as you got in your JSON? (Just to exclude the possibility that wrongful treatment of the value as an integer somewhere might have falsified it.)

Comment: @CBroe the value is right, but my app is not reviewed yet, could that be the issue? 
I though I don't need my app to be reviewed if I'm only using my own page?
any idea?

Comment: Yes, that might be it. You probably only have access to data of users that are added to one of your app roles, but not anyone outside, as long as your app is not reviewed & live.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe I'll submit for reviewing. have a good day.